# Are there any guidelines which promotes class member assignment when initialized with a mutation operation?

Tags: c++, initialization

My colleague argues that when a class member is initialized with a complex or mutation expression, then there exist a convention to use assignment instead of initialization. Are there any authorities promoting this style of class member "initialization"?

```
// Initialization
class A {
    static int counter;
    int id;
    A() : id(counter++) { }
};
int A::counter = 0;

// Assignment
class B {
    static int counter;
    int id;
    B() { 
        id = counter++;
    }
};
int B::counter = 0;
```

He argues that `B` should be used when the initializer expression is complex or mutates some other state to make it easier to spot.

Comment: How is it easier to spot? Plus, in some situations you simply cannot use assignment.

Comment: Your collegue is not correct, there is no such convention (unless it is explicilty specified by company coding guidelines) just use member list initializion. In practice I would say if you can initialize outside the body of a constructor then do so.

Comment: I guess it is easier to notice the mutation as assignment because it sticks out like a sore thumb in the body, and easier to miss when hiding up in the initializer list together with the other members.

Comment: Option C: `int id = counter++;`.

Comment: @Mestkon That's completely subjective. I don't find something easier to miss just because it is in an initializer list.

Comment: On the topic of what @Evg proposed: [C.45: Don’t define a default constructor that only initializes data members; use in-class member initializers instead](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-default)

Comment: It is of course mostly a matter of style. But, assuming C++17 or later, I would suggest to write it like this (assuming that making the constructor in your example private was a mistake): `class C { static inline int counter = 0; int id = counter++; };`. Then there is no need to choose one particular cpp to add a definition for `counter` and every constructor (if one is needed) automatically does the right thing for `id` without having to repeat yourself (except that you need to decide how copy/move should handle it).

Comment: I've never heard of your colleague's convention.  I've been programming in C++ for 34 years.  Such a convention wouldn't surprise me, but it isn't widespread.